# building custom openlayers-3 application on Window

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there a definitive guide/tutorial for building a custom version of openlayers with my application code on Windows?

I have tried both [custom builds](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/doc/tutorials/custom-builds.html) and [compiling application with closure compiler](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/doc/tutorials/closure.html) and get variety of different errors. I have looked at a variety of posts from 2014 about different 'patches' people have done but it is quite confusing to figure out what the end solution is.

I don't have access to a Linux platform to build there.  I have a prototype application running but don't want have to download the complete ol.js and goog library each time.

The errors I have been getting are:

1. 

> MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  
>   
>   But the SDK is installed....

2.

> C:\openlayers\node_modules\openlayers>node tasks\build.js build\ol-custom.json b
>   uild\ol-custom.js
>   events.js:85
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>               ^
>   Error: spawn C:\openlayers\node_modules\openlayers\node_modules.bin\jsdoc ENOEN
>   T
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
>       at child_process.js:1144:20
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

3. And `line too long...` in a post yesterday from me.

Comment: I have the same problem (2): Error: spawn ... \jsdoc ENOENT. Neither have I found an ultimate or at least working tutorial for Windows.